# Bronze Connected to Black Iron Pipe

Tags: plumbing, hvac, heating

Does bronze create corrosion when attached to black pipe for hydronic heating?

Comment: @FreeMan  The title does mention black iron pipe.

Comment: fair point, @crip659, I seem to have missed that.

Answer (score 3):

Not in my experience. I've dealt with a multitude of bronze/brass valves and sundry fittings attached to steel pipe, which had been in place for decades up to nearly a century, with no evidence of unusual corrosion. The use of brass/bronze fittings on steel/cast iron hydronic heating systems is standard practice.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about galvanic corrosion. Galvanic corrosion requires an electrolyte. Distilled water and radiator coolants are poor electrolytes (the latter by design), so fill the system with distilled water or radiator coolant (or some other poor electrolyte) and then no, bronze won't create corrosion when attached to black malleable iron pipe.